# Check minimum characters of street address using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function to check the numeric characters in a zip code. I also need to check the minimum number of characters (10) of a street address.

```
function paymentStep1(){

jQuerychk = jQuery.noConflict();
var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/; 
var zip = jQuerychk("input#id_billing_detail_postcode").val();  
if (zip.match(numbers))  {
document.getElementById("errormsssgen").innerHTML = '';
}else{      
    document.getElementById("errormsssgen").innerHTML = "ZIP code must have numeric characters only."
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where is the street address in your code?

Comment: FYI: I've seen addresses shorter than 10 characters.

Comment: I know But that's the requirement .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Validate Street Address for a minimum of 10 characters:

```
function validateStreetAddress(value){
  var l = value.trim().length;
  if (l < 10) {
    alert("Error: Street Address must be a minimum of 10 characters!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should check for leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Zee Tee's answer, you do not need a regular expression to validate the zip code, **if you do not accept spaces**. You can use the [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function instead.

```
if (!isNaN(numbers)) {
    document.getElementById("errormsssgen").innerHTML = '';
}else{      
    document.getElementById("errormsssgen").innerHTML = "ZIP code must have numeric characters only."
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
// Get the street address from the textbox first
var street_address = jQuerychk("#street_address").val();

// Now trim it for the extra spaces
street_address = jQuerychk.trim(street_address);

// Get the length of data entered as street address 
var n = street_address.length;

// Compare and get the appropiate meesage
if (n > 10) {
    jQuerychk("#errormsssgen").html('');
} else {
    jQuerychk("#errormsssgen").html('Street adress must be min length 10 chars');
    return false;
}
```